# Agregar datos a un array por medio de una api react

Tags: reactjs

Tengo el siguiente codigo. Debo agregar a un array los datos obtenidos atraves de la consulta de la api pero el boton no funciona. El boton de agregar se muestra en la descripcion del super heroe cuando muestra los resultados de la busqueda

```
<h1>Bascador</h1>
    <div>
      <input
        id="search-bar"
        type="search"
        placeholder="Buscar"
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={searchText}
      />
    </div>
    <div>
      {
      superheroData != null ? (
      superheroData.map((superhero) => 
      (
        <div className="search-result">
          <div className="left">
            <img src={superhero.image.url} alt="super pic" />
          </div>
          <div className="right">
            <h1>{superhero.name}</h1>
            <span style={{ color: "gray", marginBottom: 5 }}>
              {superhero.biography["full-name"]}
            </span>
            <div className="stats">
              <div>strength: {superhero.powerstats.strength}</div>
              <div>speed: {superhero.powerstats.speed}</div>
              <div>power: {superhero.powerstats.power}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button onClick={()=> addTeam(superhero)}>Agregar heroe al equipo</button>
        </div>
```

esta es la funcion para agegar el heroe a un array para luego mostrarlo

```
function addTeam(superhero){
    
    arrayTeam.push(superhero);
  }
```

Comment: Y ya comprobaste con un console.log que la api si te este trayendo los datos, podrias añadir el codigo completo, con la llamada a la api y los estados, falta informacion en el codigo.

Comment: Intenta usar un state para "arrayTeam" y modificar en la función addTeam con "setArrayTeam" en lugar de push, p.ej: setArrayTeam(arrayTeam.concat(superhero))" ya que se debe evitar alterar directamente el state. Igual push debería funcionar, verifica si recibiste los datos del API correctamente